# Using Python to search a sorted 2D Matrix

Tags: python, programming-challenge, matrix, complexity

[Code](https://repl.it/repls/PlushFluidRecursio)

[Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix-ii/)

```
class Solution:
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: bool
        """

        if len(matrix) == 0 or len(matrix[0]) == 0:
            return False

        height = len(matrix)
        width = len(matrix[0])

        row = height - 1 
        col = 0

        while col < width and row >= 0:
            if matrix[row][col] > target:
                row -= 1
            elif matrix[row][col] < target:
                col += 1
            else:
                return True

        return False
```

Any improvements you could make to this? Runtime is O(Len(row) + len(col)), space is constant.

I looked at other solutions and a lot of them used binary search, but that is O(len(col) * log(len(row)) so I don't think that's an improvement.

Comment: `O(n) > O(log(n))`

Comment: @alexyorke but `O(n + k) < O(n log k)` for the most part.

Comment: @Quintec ah, that is correct

Comment: You could use a binary search for both the rows and columns. I guess it would be `O(log(n) + log(m))` or `log(n + m)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using binary search both for rows and columns is not possible here. It fails if the last element of the first row is too small, i.e. for this input:

```
matrix = [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
          [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
          [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]
target = 10
```

However, you could use binary search within each row for \$\mathcal{O}(n\log m)\$ runtime, compared to your \$\mathcal{O}(n + m)\$ runtime, as you noted in the question. While this is nominally worse, for the actual testcases being tested by Leetcode it performs better.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class Solution:
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not matrix or not matrix[0]:
            return False
        for row in matrix:
            i = bisect_left(row, target)
            if i < len(row) and row[i] == target:
                return True
        return False
```

Your code: 36ms, faster than 85.35%

Binary search: 28 ms, faster than 98.39%

This is probably due to the testcases being small enough (and  if \$m = n\$, \$2n > n\log_b n\$ for \$n < b^2\$).